# Replace all values for every subgroups with subgroup min value with panda apply() function (without loop)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe df:

```
DIFF_HOURS  DIFF_TEMP
0   0.0     0.050886
1   1.0     0.660698
2   2.0     1.656014
3   3.0     2.543857
4   4.0     3.071813
...     ...     ...
627647  68.0    -1.708911
627648  69.0    -1.225022
627649  70.0    -2.040668
627650  71.0    -2.738665
```

For data visualization, I do various boxplot with x=DIFF_HOURS and y=DIFF_TEMP.

I want to have subgroups of 6 hours:

```
Group 1: 0, 1, 2, 3,4,6
Group 2: 7,8,9,10,11,12
...
Group n: 66,67,68,69,70,71,72
```

And replace all values of each subgroup by min subgroup value:

```
Group 1: 0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 2: 7,7,7,7,7,7
...
Group n: 66,66,66,66,66,66
```

I don't want to use a loop. Is it possible to use panda apply() function please?

Comment: `apply` is as inefficient as using a loop

Comment: are the hours consecutive? Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Your current example is ambiguous as you have apparently 627650 rows but only 71 hours

Comment: @mozway: 627650 / 365 / 24 almost equal to 72

Comment: Hi sorry. I have only 72 differents hours but a same hours is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(df['DIFF_HOURS'].mod(6).eq(0).cumsum())['DIFF_HOURS'].apply(lambda x: [x.min()]*6)
```

Comment: Hi thanks. If I have only 72 differents hours, a same hours is repeated several times.

Answer (score 0):

My solution whick works fine and fast:

```
every_hours = 6
max_periode = 72

for i in range(0, max_periode, every_hours):
      df.loc[(df['DIFF_HOURS'] > i) & (df['DIFF_HOURS'] <= (i+6)), 'DIFF_HOURS'] = i
```